# Get current process CPU usage in C

Tags: c, unix, cross-platform, process-management

On Windows I can do:

```
HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();

FILETIME ftCreation, ftExit, ftKernel, ftUser;

GetProcessTimes(hProcess, &ftCreation, &ftExit, &ftKernel, &ftUser);

SYSTEMTIME stKernel;
FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftKernel, &stKernel);

SYSTEMTIME stUser;
FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftUser, &stUser);

printf("Time in kernel mode = %uh %um %us %ums", stKernel.wHour,
           stKernel.wMinute, stKernel.wSecond, stKernel.wMilliseconds));
printf("Time in user mode = %uh %um %us %ums", stUser.wHour,
           stUser.wMinute, stUser.wSecond, stUser.wMilliseconds));
```

How can I do the same thing on *nix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [getrusage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage), I think that should solve your problem.